# Write on a file the volume of a drive plus random text

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system, drive

I am trying to write on a volume of E drive. But in that file I also want to add some random text like just "random text".
How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
import os.path
textFile=os.system("vol E: > file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate random text you can import *random* module, then make a list of random words or characters and then add them together

```
import random
import os

words = ['dog', 'pizza', 'pasta', 'Giovanni', 'lasagne', 'salame', 'pecorino']  # make a list of words or characters

minimum_words = 3
maximum_words = 10
random_text = ''
for i in range(random.randint(minimum_words, maximum_words)): # uses as range a random integer number between 3 and 10
    random_text += random.choice(words) + ' ' # choose a random word from the list

os.system(f"vol E: {random_text} > file.txt") # use f strings
```

Hope this solved your problem, good night